# Having trouble understanding the yield part of this code

Tags: python, yield

Brand-spanking new here.  New to coding, if you don't count having learned coding 25 years ago in school but never employed IRL.

This is an example from the book Python In Easy Steps:

```
def fibonacci_generator():
    a=b=1

    while True:
        yield a
        a, b=b, a+b

fib = fibonacci_generator()

for i in fib:
    if i>100:
        break
    else:
        print('Generated', i)
```

I can more or less follow the definition of the generator (I know it's not a function; that counts for something, right?) and the definition of the fib variable and for loop.

But I'm not getting the lines for yield:

```
while True:
        yield a
        a, b=b, a+b
```

Can someone walk me through this?  For instance:

- While "what" is True??  Where would this ever become False?
- Assume **a** starts at 1, what does **yield a** give me, vs what does **a, b=b, a+b** give me?
- Where *exactly* in this code is **a** getting redefined/reset in value (sorry if wrong terminology) from 1 to 2, from 2 to 3, from 3 to 5, etc?

Comment: `While "what" is True??` While the condition is truthy. `True` is truthy. It never ends. `Where exactly in this code is a getting redefined/reset in value` In `a, b=b, a+b`.

Comment: *”While "what" is True”* — While `True` is true. Which it obviously always is. Hence this is an endless loop.

Comment: `while True` means loop indefinitely (since `True` will always be, well, `True`). `a, b = b, a+b` redefines the left hand side of the equal sign, namely both `a` and `b`.

Comment: Thanks on the While True is True.  I think I understand that now. @Selcuk - OK i didn't understand your response, but I think I do now.  I was looking at this like it was three different things, but now I see it's more like (a, b) = (b, a+b).  Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
while True:
```

The `while` statement checks whether the right-hand value is true. If yes, it performs another loop, and if no, it breaks out of the loop. This statement loops indefinitely.

```py
yield a
```

In a generator, this is sort of like a `return` statement, except that it lets the generator function continue executing. This statement enables the program to execute so that the generator gives values to the caller in between execution and does not have to run all the way to end (which in this case is infinity).

```py
a, b=b, a+b
```

This is simply a Pythonic way of assigning values to variables. It is called multiple assignment and it works as follows:

```py
variable1, variable2, ... varaibleN = value1, value2, ... valueN
```

---

If `a` starts at `1`, the next time `a` is referred to is in `yield a`, and it will yield `1`.

---

`a` is assigned a new value at `a, b = b, a + b`.

Comment: Note that the double assignment is *not* the same as two separate assignments, since the values influence each other…!

Comment: Thanks.  I had been reading a, b = b, a + b like it was three different i-don't-know-what's (my first time seeing the yield statement), rather than (a,b) = (b, a+b).  I probably should have paid more attention to the spaces when I copied it from the book into my script.  Makes so much more sense now.